# Instantiate class with automatically using dependency types added in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Example code:

```
public class A
{
public DoWork()
{
   //how to Instantiate an object of class B with automatically using dependency service types added in Startup.cs and IServiceCollection?
   var b = some resolver logic here to get new B();//need help here
   b.InnerWork();
}
}

public class B
   //What can help pass the configured dependency types and give a new instance of B?
   public B(Dep1 one, Dep2 two) {}
   function bool InnerWork() {}
```

Can't seem to find syntax to access the IServiceCollection or a resolver that would help make an instance of class B.

Comment: Is there any reason to not inject `B` into `A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question properly:

```
public class A
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
    public A(IServiceProvider provider) =>
        _provider = provider;
    
    public void DoWork()
    {
        var scope = _provider.CreateScope();
        var b = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<B>();
        b.InnerWork();
    }
```

Or you can inject B into A instead of using IServiceProvider like the previous author said.